# Tkinter GUI root.after()

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello i'm trying to make a simple speedtest GUI with python, i wanted it with a go and a stop button, after clicking go button it would run speedtest until stop button is clicked but when i click go i see from the print statements that it enter the while loop and executes the print statements but it completely ignores the window.after(30000, test) command. Also it ignores the stop button once looping ending in having to close the window and recieving a python is not responding message.

```
import speedtest
from tkinter import *

isOn = False

def test():
    st = speedtest.Speedtest()
    st.get_best_server()
    download = round(st.download()/(1024*1024),2)
    upload = round(st.upload()/(1024*1024),2)
    ping = int(st.results.ping)

    dwn.config(text="D: "+str(download)+" Mbps")
    up.config(text="D: " + str(upload) + " Mbps")
    pin.config(text="D: " + str(ping) + " ms")
    

def switchOn():
isOn = True
while isOn:
    print("start loop")
    window.after(30000, test)
    print("end loop")

def switchOff():
    isOn = False

window = Tk()

mainframe = Frame(window, bg="black")
dwn = Label(mainframe, text="Download", bg="black", fg="white")
up = Label(mainframe, text="Upload", bg="black", fg="white")
pin = Label(mainframe, text="Ping", bg="black", fg="white")
btn = Button(mainframe, text="go", bg="black", fg="green", activebackground="green", command=switchOn)
btn2 = Button(mainframe, text="stop", bg="black", fg="red", activebackground="red", command=switchOff)
mainframe.pack()
dwn.grid(row=0, column=1)
up.grid(row=0, column=2)
pin.grid(row=0, column=3)
btn.grid(row=0, column=4)
btn2.grid(row=0, column=5)

window.mainloop()
```

this is my code at the moment can anyone help me?

Comment: Search this site for the use of `time.sleep` in a GUI. In short, you shouldn't do it. There are _many_ questions about that, it's a very common mistake.

Comment: if by crash you mean t stops to respond, follow @BryanOakley tip and forget the `time.sleep`. You shouldn't be using this together with tkinter. But if after 60 seconds of wait your program raise an error, please specify the error message and what is the `speedtest` module you are importing

Comment: I took away time.sleep() and replaced it with root.after() which is what i found in other questions but it ignores the command, I edited the question and code, i'll keep looking but if you have any other suggestions they are appreciated!

Comment: For the duration of your `while` loop (which is forever), those three lines of code are *the only thing your program is doing*.  You're printing a lot of text, and scheduling an infinite number of calls to `test()` 30 seconds into the future, but that future never arrives because you're not ever giving Tkinter a chance to process events.  You have to return to the mainloop for `.after()` to accomplish anything.

Comment: so root.after() doesn't wait 30 sec but goes on and postpones by 30 sec? how would i return to mainloop?